# php registration is not responding

Tags: php, html

i made a php registration [here](http://peterbousaada.cf/signup.html)
heres my html and php :
html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="validation-script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="peterbousaada.cf">Peter Bou Saada</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="peterbousaada.cf">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="peter.html">About Me</a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="signup.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<form id="contact-form" action="signup.php" method="post">
<div>
<label>
    <span>Full Name<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input name="name" type="text" Placeholder="Your Full Name" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>Username<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input name="uname" type="text" Placeholder="Your Desired Username" tabindex="1" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>E-mail<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input name="email" type="email" Placeholder="Your E-mail" tabindex="2" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>Password<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input id="pwd" name="password" type="password" Placeholder="Your New Password" tabindex="3" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>Retype Password<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input id="repwd" name="repassword" type="password" Placeholder="Retype Password" tabindex="4" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

php :

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['repassword'];

$name =mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$uname =mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$email =mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password =mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$password2 =mysql_real_escape_string($password2);

if ($password != $password2){
    echo "Error! Passwords do not match."
}
else{
$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else {
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email,name ,username,password )
VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$uname', '$password')";}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "registered!";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

ok so i am 100% sure that the connection is working because i setup this small test [here](http://peterbousaada.cf/connectiontest.php).
basically if it didnt connect to the db it will say Error : error-name
but in my case it is saying connected.
so i was wondering if there is anything wrong with my code,
and if some1 can give me email and username checker to check if they already exist in the db, i am fairly new to php

Comment: I suggest you tell us what the actual issue is... Or are we meant to _guess_ that?

Comment: i have found that an else tag was missing the ending " } ", i added it but still nothing

Comment: I suggest you start looking into your http servers error log file. That is where php writes its errors. There is little sense in trying to _guess_ what the issue might be if you can _read_ what it is in there. That error log file should always be the first thing to consult in case of issues with php scripts running inside an http server.

Comment: my issue is that i got all that php code, and its not running, you can go to peterbousaada.cf/signup.html and try to sign up, all u face is a blank page

Comment: I do believe you, no need for me to look at a white page. As said: take a look into your http servers error log file. What do you read in there?

Comment: @PeterBouSaada, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/vol15_1/vxhost.cf/vxh_16565917/peterbousaada.cf/htdocs/signup.php on line 7 - i am getting this. always check where the error line is maybe you missed/misstyped a few characters.

Comment: Why are you mixing two DB apis (`mysql_` and `mysqli_`)? Also, why are you escaping instead of using parametrized queries? And are you **seriously storing plaintext passwords?!**

Comment: Thank u guys turns out my hosting had php error log turned off so i turned it on, saw all the errors and fixed them, and yes i noticed that i was overriding the inputed password , i just have one question, can i use header(location:urlhere)to take them to a register successful page ?

Answer (score 1):

You have syntactical errors on line 7 of `signup.php`, thus your **PHP is not executed** at all.

Besides that, this has some logical errors:

You are overwriting he password provided by the user to register with your DB password because of wrong variable usage and scope:

```
...
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['repassword'];

$name =mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$uname =mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$email =mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password =mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$password2 =mysql_real_escape_string($password2);

if ($password != $password2){
    echo "Error! Passwords do not match."
}
else{
$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword"; // <<<<< you are overwriting the users registration password here!
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
...
```